# Why isn't my code working in command line?

Tags: python, command-line, tiff, gdal, attributeerror

I am using Python3.6 and I need to run my code in command line. The code works when I run it in PyCharm but when I use command line I get this error:

```
 File "path", line 43, in <module>
     rb = ds.GetRasterBand(1) 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetRasterBand'
```

It seems that I have a problem with these lines:

```
ds = gdal.Open('tif_file.tif', gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
rb = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
img_array = rb.ReadAsArray()
```

Does anyone know what I might have done wrong?

EDIT

Some magic just happened. I tried to run my code this morning and everything seems fine. I guess what my computer needed was a restart or something. Thanks to you all for help.

Comment: The path to the file is *relative*, and is really equal to `./tif_file.tif`. When you run from the command-line, is the file in the *current directory*?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: In the command-line environment, if you run `ls` or `dir` (depending on operating system), is your file listed?

Comment: I get this: {18/02/09  04:55 AM         3,126,394 tif_file.tif
               1 File(s)      3,126,394 bytes
               0 Dir(s)   6,252,511,232 bytes free}. How do I know if it is listed?

Comment: Did you try to specify the full path of your file?

Comment: Yes. I get the same result

Comment: Make sure you're enabling errors with [`UseExceptions()`](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/PythonGotchas). Also consider using rasterio instead of GDAL directly.

Comment: UseExeptions() didn't help. I will try rasterio

Answer (score 0):

[from the gdal documentation:](https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html)

```
from osgeo import gdal
dataset = gdal.Open(filename, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
if not dataset:
    ...
```

> Note that if GDALOpen() returns NULL it means the open failed, and
> that an error messages will already have been emitted via CPLError().
> If you want to control how errors are reported to the user review the
> CPLError() documentation. Generally speaking all of GDAL uses
> CPLError() for error reporting. Also, note that pszFilename need not
> actually be the name of a physical file (though it usually is). It's
> interpretation is driver dependent, and it might be an URL, a filename
> with additional parameters added at the end controlling the open or
> almost anything. Please try not to limit GDAL file selection dialogs
> to only selecting physical files.

---

looks like the file you are trying to open is not a valid gdal file or some other magic is going on in the file selection. you could try to direct the program to a known good file online to test it.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but unfortunately nothing changes when I insert your lines into my code :/. How would I direct my program to online file? (Sorry, I am not an experienced programmer)

Comment: `UseExceptions()` is [preferred](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/PythonGotchas) to checking error codes manually.